# Logarithmic y axis makes tick labels disappear

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis-labels

Upon adding the line `plt.yscale('log')` to my simple plotting script

```
import numpy as np
residuals = np.loadtxt('res_jacobi.txt', skiprows=1)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()

steps = np.arange(0, len(residuals), 1)

plt.plot(steps, residuals, label='$S$')

plt.xlabel("Step",fontsize=20)
plt.ylabel("$S$",fontsize=20)
plt.ylim(0.95 * min(residuals), 1.05 * max(residuals))
plt.yscale('log')

plt.savefig('jacobi-res.pdf', bbox_inches='tight', transparent=True)
```

the y labels disappear.

[image][image]

I'm sure there is simple fix for this but searching did not turn one up. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: seems like a bug, but you might try using `semilogy` http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.semilogy

Comment: @DavidMaust I don't think this is a bug, in log-scaling only the major tick-marks are labeled which are orders of magnitude.  This is definitely not *optimal* behavior... however

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The normal behavior for `matplotlib` is to only label major tick marks in log-scaling --- which are even orders of magnitude, e.g. `{0.1, 1.0}`.  Your values are all between those.  You can:

- rescale your axes to larger bounds,
  `plt.gca().set_ylim(0.1, 1.0)`
- label the tick-marks manually,
  `plt.gca().yaxis.set_minor_formatter(FormatStrFormatter("%.2f"))`

Comment: With `plt.gca().set_yscale('semilog')`, it get the error `ValueError: Unknown scale type 'semilog'`. `plt.gca().set_yscale('log')` executes but still suffers from lack of labels. `plt.gca().set_ylim(0.1, 1.0)` works but choosing bounds sufficiently large to have y labels appear almost makes the plot look constant (yes, I know this means using a log scale is not necessary in the first place, but I'm just following instructions here). Thankfully, `plt.gca().yaxis.set_minor_formatter(FormatStrFormatter("%.2f"))` works great. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`semilogy` works for me.

Change:

```
plt.plot(steps, residuals, label='$S$')
```

Into:

```
plt.semilogy(steps, residuals, label='$S$')
```

Remove `plt.yscale('log')`

Comment: Thanks for the tip but this does not change anything for me.